# Qt main window destructor not called on exit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtgui

I am coding a fairly simple application that uses Qt with OpenCV.  I have single window that contains a widget which displays a video feed captured from a webcam.  The webcam video capture is running in an infinite loop in a separate thread so as not to consume the UI thread.

When I close the window (using the normal "X" button on the top right of the window - this app is being developed in Windows 7), it doesn't seem to be shutting down the program correctly.  The window does close visibly, but I put a breakpoint in the destructor of the main window, and the breakpoint never gets hit.  Additionally, the thread which does video capture continues to run (I know this because the thread outputs to stdout periodically).  Only when I click "stop debugging" in the Qt development environment does it cause everything to completely shut down.

Here is my worker object (not subclassing from QThread):

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    VideoCapture *cap;
    bool finished;
    QMutex mutex;
public:
    Worker ()
    {
        cap = new VideoCapture(0);
        finished = false;
    }

    bool isFinished ()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker (&mutex);
        return finished;
    }

public slots:
    void doWork ()
    {
        Mat frame;
        while(!isFinished())
        {
            // ...some code that outputs to stdout deleted for clarity...
            (*cap) >> frame;
            emit resultReady(frame);
        }
    }

    void setFinished (bool f)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker (&mutex);
        finished = f;
    }

signals:
    void resultReady (Mat frame);
};
```

Here is the header file for my main window:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    CVImageWidget* imageWidget;
    Worker *worker;
    QThread workerThread;

public slots:
    void handleResults (Mat frame);

signals:
    void operate ();
    void finishSignal (bool f);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

And the class implementation:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Create a widget for this window.
    QWidget *wdg = new QWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(wdg);

    // ...code creating widgets deleted for clarity...

    this->setCentralWidget(wdg);

    //Start video capture
    qRegisterMetaType<Mat>("Mat");
    worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(operate()), worker, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(resultReady(Mat)), this, SLOT(handleResults(Mat)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finishSignal(bool)), worker, SLOT(setFinished(bool)));

    workerThread.start();
    emit operate();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    emit finishSignal(true);
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::handleResults(Mat frame)
{
    imageWidget->showImage(frame);
}
```

Any help understanding why the program doesn't shut down properly would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you set `qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);` ? if so, that might be the problem. If not, it could be because the library you are using doesn't clean up its thread properly. You could try `exit(a.exec());` instead of `return a.exec();` in your main function...

Comment: I haven't called setQuitOnLastWindowClosed anywhere in my code, and by default it should be set to true according to the docs.  After reading your comment, I tried setting it to true just to make sure, but it had no effect.  I tried callic exit(a.exec()), and that had a curious behavior to it.  It seems like the thread must have stopped, because my output in each execution of doWork() stopped, but it still didn't exit the program cleanly.

Comment: I think we also need to see your main() or wherever your MainWindow is created. It won't be destructed just by closing the window, and until then your threads are still running.

Comment: So I did some further investigation.  It turns out my destructor is actually being called, it just doesn't seem to be sending the signal to the worker object to finish up and close down.  Is there something I'm doing wrong in my setup of the signals and slots?

Comment: Your slot `setFinished()` is never called. Qt would execute the slot in the worker thread itself. But the worker thread is busy with running `doWork()`. One solution would be to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` inside the loop. This function would handle the events of the thread that called it. This means it would call `setFinished()` if the signal was send already. You do not need `QMutexLocker locker` inside `setFinished()` since it is called synchronously inside the worker thread as long as your are using signals to inform the worker.